# How to setup authorization with .htaccess for smartphones?

Tags: android, ios, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a page where I have username and password authorization defined in `.htaccess` and it works fine on all my devices.

However, some people using smartphones have complained that it does not work. Their problem description is that they don't get a login box. Not having a smartphone myself, I cannot check this on my own. One of them said she is using Android 7.0

This is my `.htaccess`

```
Options +Indexes
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Ask the board about username and password"
AuthUserFile /path/to/restricted/area/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
ErrorDocument 401 "Ask the board about username and password"
```

and `.htpassword`

```
user:$apr1$9QlPO64A$6xpOE5lWDZgfHUp3LSB/p0
```

The workaround I'm using at the moment is using the url `http://user:pass@example.com` but it is not a preferable solution for a couple of reasons.

Is this a known issue on modern devices? Is there any more modern method I should use instead?

Comment: `smartfones` is completely wrong definition. 1) there are completely different OSes, which should never be treated as something of same kind. Probably the problem is observed on one OS, and not on another. 2) Even for the same OS, you are able to use huge amount of different web browsers, which means that in one web browser it might work, and in another - it wont. So you will have to get details of which OS and browser the users, who face problems, use.

Comment: @VladMatvienko That was my guess too, so I basically wonder if the method I'm using is outdated for some reason, an if so, what should you use today?